# Retrieve text from a textarea after submission

Tags: php, html, forms

Say I have a page with a textarea which acts as an input.
Then I have a Submit button and right under everything i have the
output textarea.

Now what I want to do is when the input has been submitted and
sent into the output text area, how can I then retrieve the text from the output area.

This is the code i have:

```
    <head>

    <?php error_reporting(0);
         $OutputText = $_GET['OutputText'];  
     ?>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="#" method="_GET">

        <textarea name="InputText">
            hi
        </textarea>

        <input type="submit" name="submitFirstInput">

    </form>

    <textarea name="OutputText">
        <?php echo $_GET['InputText']; ?>
    </textarea>

    <hr>

    <p>Output String Length: <?php echo strlen($OutputText);  ?> </p>

</body>
```

for reasons I dont understand, it cant define the $OutputText,
Do they both have to be in a form? As i have understood form's is only to send data, and testing it didn't help much either.

Keep in mind this is just a barebones version of the original, essentially i have some Input text and then through some logic it gets modified, therefor i want some statistics for the output result. So just getting the first input isnt rather useful..

Comment: change method to get and not _GET

Comment: What do you expect `$_GET['OutputText']` to be? You never defined anthing similar to it? The only thing that is defined is `$_GET['InputText']`

Comment: **Danger**: This code is [vulnerable to XSS](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS) User input needs escaping before being inserted into an HTML document!.

Comment: `method="_GET"` — What is that underscore doing there? Use [a validator](https://validator.nu).

Comment: @Xatenev not sure what you mean here, $_GET['OutputText'] should be the last textarea, as i named it OutputText

Comment: @Dice You are never submitting it - it is not even inside the `<form>`. To output the string length of the submitted string you could just use `<?php echo strlen($_GET['InputText']); ?>` But I don't understand the purpose of anything in this code snippet. Why those two text areas? Why `error_reporting(0);` while in development?

Comment: @Xatenev Ooh i see where i went wrong, but if i put the other textarea inside the same form, then i will have to press it Twice to get the OutputString length? The erroreporting is since if the page is not submitted it will always show an error that something aint defined, I commented it out though. + I mentioned how this was a barebones version, theres actually alot more to add to this its just if i added all of unnecessary code it be harder to figure out the question.

Comment: @Dice Yea the error is completly fine - fix the error in your code, use `empty()` and/or `isset` to check whether your variables exist that you want to use before. **Removing error_reporting is no solution**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

adding some javascript you can sync the two textarea:

```
        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html lang="">

        <head>
            <title></title>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <script>
                $(window).load(function(){
                    $("#one, #two").on("change keyup", function(){
                        $("textarea").not($(this)).val($(this).val());
                    });
                });
            </script>

        </head>

        <body>
            <form action="#" method="GET">
                <textarea name="InputText" id="one"></textarea>
                <textarea name="OutputText" id="two"></textarea>
                <input type="submit" name="submitFirstInput">
            </form>

            <hr>
            <?php echo '<pre>'; var_dump($_GET); echo '</pre>'; ?>

            <p>Output String Length:
                <?php echo strlen($_GET['OutputText']);  ?> </p>

        </body>

        </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Textarea must be inside the form tag, and the method must be GET (or POST)
try this:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="">

    <head>
        <title></title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="#" method="GET">
            <textarea name="InputText">hi</textarea>
            <input type="submit" name="submitFirstInput">
            <textarea name="OutputText"><?php echo $_GET['InputText']; ?></textarea>
        </form>
        <hr>
        <?php //echo '<pre>'; var_dump($_GET); echo '</pre>'; ?>

        <p>Output String Length: <?php echo strlen($_GET['OutputText']);  ?> </p>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Indeed this works but with this solution I would have to press the submit button twice to get the Output string length, how would i fix this?

Comment: @Dice Use `<?php echo strlen($_GET['InputText']); ?>`. I don't understand the whole point of the 2nd textarea.

Comment: @Xatenev well say if someone inputs some symbols so 10051 and then i have some logic code that turns 10051 into e.g "A" so now whenever 10051 is enter it out puts A, now i want to see the string length difference between these two fields, then i would need to get te output string length and echo that out ..